# Unexpected Error while executing imgkit

Tags: python, python-3.x, imgkit

I'm a newbie to Python, While learning imgkit (PI module) I got this error which was not expected for a simple code. Below is the code

```
import imgkit

imgkit.from_url('https://www.google.co.in/','fs.jpg')
```

and the error which I got is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\python\lib\site-packages\imgkit-0.1.8-py3.6.egg\imgkit\config.py", line 30, in __init__
    with open(self.wkhtmltoimage):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALEXANDER\Desktop\def img.py", line 3, in <module>
    imgkit.from_url('https://www.google.co.in/','fs.jpg')
  File "G:\python\lib\site-packages\imgkit-0.1.8-py3.6.egg\imgkit\api.py", line 20, in from_url
    rtn = IMGKit(url, 'url', options=options, toc=toc, cover=cover, config=config, cover_first=cover_first)
  File "G:\python\lib\site-packages\imgkit-0.1.8-py3.6.egg\imgkit\imgkit.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.config = Config() if not config else config
  File "G:\python\lib\site-packages\imgkit-0.1.8-py3.6.egg\imgkit\config.py", line 36, in __init__
    'http://wkhtmltopdf.org\n'.format(self.wkhtmltoimage))
OSError: No wkhtmltoimage executable found: "b''"
If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - http://wkhtmltopdf.org
```

Could anyone tell me what mistake I have done.

Comment: error said "if this file exists...please install wkhtmltopdf - http://wkhtmltopdf.org." so try to install that module.

Answer (score 6):

you need to these lines after installing wkhtmltopdf on your windows system:

```
path_wkthmltoimage = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltoimage.exe'
config = imgkit.config(wkhtmltoimage=path_wkthmltoimage)

imgkit.from_file('table.html', 'table.jpg',config=config)
```

Answer (score -1):

try: `brew install caskroom/cask/wkhtmltopdf`

Answer (score -3):

It looks like you need to install wkhtmltopdf. To do so, run `pip install wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: I had tried to install wkhtmltopdf installation is not getting completed [link](https://imgur.com/a/ooBNU)  downloaded a fresh copy from pypi still same result. Even tried with wkhtmltopdf 0.1 but no progress. Did anyone else encountered this problem

Comment: This doesnt help and it is for converting to pdf.